# How to find by xpath with Selenium Webdriver? (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am creating a program that scrapes dictionary definitions. I am using LINE Dictionary, which can be found here: [LINE Dictonary](http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/home). I type in the word "汤" like so:

[Image of current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyUCD.png)

As you can see, the word has 2 definitions. How do I grab both of them using Selenium Webdriver? Here is a snippet of the HTML for them. If it is not enough, I recommend going to LINE Dict and typing in "汤". Thank you!

[snippet of the definition's HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJanD.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: definition_list = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('ol.lst_defin>li span.cn')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPATH :

```
//div[@id='autocplt_wrap']//descendant::span[@class='word']//a[text()='汤']
```

CSS_SELECTOR for grabbing those two element would be :

```
ol.lst_defin>li span.cn
```

UPDATE :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/home")

input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='text']")
input.send_keys("汤")
input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  

asian_text= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='autocplt_wrap']//descendant::span[@class='word']//a[text()='汤']")))  
asian_text.click();  


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ol.lst_defin>li span.cn')))

definition_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('ol.lst_defin>li span.cn') 
print(len(definition_list)) 

for element in definition_list :
 print(element.text)
```

This will print :

**[??] hot water

soup**

Comment: It works! However, the value is hard coded :/ how would you make it so that this part: //a[text()='汤'] works with any other word inside?

Comment: You can have a[text()='"+any_word+"']

Comment: where any_word will be a variable.

Comment: For using the css selector, would I use : find_elements_by_css_selector('ol.lst_defin>li span.cn')?

Comment: Yes , remember that will return a list of web element , then you can iterate over that list and extract the value of each web element.

Comment: Hm, for some reason it returns an empty list :(

Comment: you can have explicit wait before retrieving the web element.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but may I please see how that would be integrated? I am new to selenium, thank you so much for the help sir.

Comment: when you print this : len(definition_list ) , could you tell me the output. and please avoid saying sir.

Comment: Here: browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('ol.lst_defin>li span.cn') OUTPUT: 0

Comment: you can something like : WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ol.lst_defin>li span.cn'))
)

Comment: for more on explicit wait, you can refer : http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Ah! here is the new output now: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="35b56f2540aeff38d7341d6dbee51e40", element="0.643731003025164-3")> How would I extract the definition now? Hm..

Comment: @BryanThai : I have updated my answer under update section , you can get it from there. and the length of list is 2

Comment: Your code works beautifully! Thank you very much. The thing is, I still have a question about how to grab the right data. For example, I want to grab the word "tang" which appears under the Asian text. How would I use a CSS selector like you did with 'ol.lst_defin>li span.cn'? EDIT: I want to learn how to write something like "ol.lst_defin>li span.cn". How did you arrive at this? Thank you!

Comment: use this css selector :   div.prnc_area>span

Comment: right_side_word = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(" div.prnc_area>span") , then using text method you can get the text

Comment: Thanks again. You've helped me so much with this :D

Comment: @Bryan :no problem.